# Backup software which lets you easily switch between different versions of a file or directory

Tags: linux, backup, command-line

Is there a backup software for linux which lets you switch easily between different versions of a directory or a file in the backup in command line?

It should have a mature completion support for zsh.

Here is something like that for my own backup script: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/294280/best-way-to-browse-different-versions-of-a-backup-of-a-directory/294380#294380

For borg backup there is a feature request in this direction: https://github.com/borgbackup/borg/issues/2462

I am looking for other systems with mature features in this direction for command line users.

Comment: Do you know what a version control system is? If yes, could you define why a version control system does not suit your needs?

Comment: @ThomasWeller not really fitting for all backups – but of course a good idea. Another one would be a variant of RSync backup. I e.g. happily use [RSync-Push-Backup](https://github.com/SebKuzminsky/rsync-push-backup). Restore is a simple copy from the corresponding "snapshot". But switching back *and forth* would be tricky, as once an "older version" has been restored it would go into the next backup again, so one needed to remember where which version was. Or not have the backups running automatically (this one is intended to run hourly in the background).